# Faster VBA VLookup alternative to retrieving data based on a key

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to match a large dataset and copy the values from one sheet to another using VBA. I'm currently using Vlookup, but the process is so slow for even the single column that I'm testing with that it is not viable. Is there a more efficient way to match data based on a key? Essentially my data looks like this, where I am trying to copy the 'Data' from Dataset A to B, using the 'Key'

Dataset A:

```
Key  Data
123  yes
231  yes
435  no
```

Dataset B:

```
Key  Data
453  
231
```

My code currently is as follows:

```
    Sub copyData()

Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim backlogSheet As Worksheet
Dim combinedSheet As Worksheet

Set backlogSheet = Sheets("All SAMs Backlog")
Set combinedSheet = Sheets("COMBINED")
myLastRow = backlogSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For myRow = 3 To myLastRow

    curLoc = backlogSheet.Cells(myRow, "C")

    searchVal = Range("D" & myRow).Value

    statusVal = Application.VLookup(curLoc, combinedSheet.Range("A:B"), 2, False)

    'Range("D" & myRow).Cells.Value = testVal
Next myRow

MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use Power Query and do a merge.

Comment: Why don't you just enter the Vlookup into the first worksheet cell, then copy down? If you don't want to leave the formula, copy the column and paste special Values on itself to retain the found values.

Comment: @teylyn The amount of data would require many vlookups, which results in a filesize that is simply too large and slow. As for pasting the values, it is not practical and leaves room for error. I want to avoid doing that at all costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate a dictionary from the source, get an array of the target and fill it with the source dictionary and finally, drop the array of results back onto the target worksheet.

```
Sub copyData()
    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant, dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("COMBINED")
        'put combined!a:b into a variant array
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
        'loop through array and build dictionary keys from combined!a:a, dictionary item from combined!b:b
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            dict.Item(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)
        Next i
    End With

    With Worksheets("All SAMs Backlog")
        'put 'all sams backlog'!c:d into a variant array
        arr = .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)).Value2
        'loop through array and if c:c matches combined!a:a then put combined!b:b into d:d
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If dict.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
                arr(i, 2) = dict.Item(arr(i, 1))
            Else
                arr(i, 2) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next i
        'put populated array back into c3 (resized by rows and columns)
        .Cells(3, "C").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With

    MsgBox ("done")

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly, and so quick too! However I don't entirely understand what's going on. Could you perhaps comment it, and I'll mark as answer. Because I want to apply this to other columns, but it's quick tricky to figure out what to re-use and where. Also would help others who come across this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! So if I were to want to do the same process for another column in addition to the one used currently, would there be much work required? I think I would change B to C in the 'COMBINED' loop, but where to from there?

Comment: All the particulars and intricacies would seem to be too numerous to discuss in comments so that might be a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I've worked on it myself and got 90% of it done. Struggling with the last 10%, and posted a new question. If you know the answer, feel free! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50711552/vba-find-and-replace-not-working-for-all-columns)