# VBA find and replace not working for all columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am using a piece of code that loops through a Excel worksheet, uses the keys from it to copy another set of data into it. The two datasets (Dataset A to Dataset B) looks like following:

Dataset A:

```
Key  Val1  Val2  Val3
123  yes   up    right
324  no    down  right
314  no    up    left
```

Dataset B:

```
Key  Val1  Val2  Val3
123
314
324
```

When the script is ran, it copies the data based on the Key. My code works for Val1 and Val2, but results in only blank entries for Val3, which is unexpected and unwanted. My code is as follows:

```
    Sub copyData()
    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant, dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("COMBINED")
        'put combined!a:d into a variant array
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value2
        'loop through array and build dictionary keys from combined!a:a, dictionary item from rows b:d
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            dict.Item(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)
            dict.Item(arr(i, 2)) = arr(i, 3)
            dict.Item(arr(1, 3)) = arr(1, 4)
        Next i
    End With

    With Worksheets("All SAMs Backlog")
        arr = .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3)).Value2
        'loop through array and if c:c matches combined!a:a then put combined!b:b into d:d
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If dict.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
                arr(i, 2) = dict.Item(arr(i, 1))
                arr(i, 3) = dict.Item(arr(i, 2))
                arr(i, 4) = dict.Item(arr(i, 3))
            Else
                arr(i, 2) = vbNullString
                arr(i, 3) = vbNullString
                arr(i, 4) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next i
        'put populated array back into c3 (resized by rows and columns)
        .Cells(3, "C").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With

    MsgBox ("done")

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have `dict.Item(arr(1, 3)) = arr(1, 4)` instead of `dict.Item(arr(i, 3)) = arr(i, 4)` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Combined column A as the dictionary key and combine the multiple columns into an array to be stored as the dictionary Item

```
Sub tranferData()
    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant, dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("COMBINED")
        'put combined!a:d into a variant array
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value2
        'loop through array and build dictionary keys from combined!a:a, dictionary item from rows b:d
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            'add key and multiple items as array
            If not dict.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then _
              dict.Add Key:=arr(i, 1), Item:=Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4))
        Next i
    End With

    With Worksheets("All SAMs Backlog")
        arr = .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3)).Value2
        'loop through array and if c:c matches combined!a:a then put combined!b:d into d:f
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If dict.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
                arr(i, 2) = dict.Item(arr(i, 1))(0)
                arr(i, 3) = dict.Item(arr(i, 1))(1)
                arr(i, 4) = dict.Item(arr(i, 1))(2)
            Else
                arr(i, 2) = vbNullString
                arr(i, 3) = vbNullString
                arr(i, 4) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next i
        'put populated array back into c3 (resized by rows and columns)
        .Cells(3, "C").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With

    MsgBox ("done")

End Sub
```

Comment: See the error control I added for the dict.add method. The earlier shorthand version doesn't need it as it overwrites duplicates. dict.add key, item requires it or it will choke on duplicates.